# different maker icons - android mapview

Tags: android, icons, overlay, android-mapview, markers

```
public class MapOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    ....
    public MapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        //super(defaultMarker);
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }
    ....
```

}

MapOverlay class gets drawable as a constructor argument. Is is possible to change that image when drawing point on the map?
What I want do is to write markers with different icon images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Drawable marker = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.youricon);
```

Comment: ok, but after then I want to add several points (with different icons) how can I do that?

Comment: i changed my answer and put you icon as per requirements